# How to select all text except pattern

Tags: regex

I have a textfile, and I want to get all the translated strings from it.

All translations are like so:

`_('string')`

So I have this regex:

`(_\(['"].+['"]\))`

Which finds all my translations... now how do I invert this so I can delete everything else?

i ended up doing:

`egrep "_\('.+?)" ~myfile.py -o >> ~/Desktop/translations.txt`

`egrep '_\(".+?)' ~myfile.py -o >> ~/Desktop/translations.txt`

I couldn't even do it in one shot because I didn't know how to escape the single quote in the shell :(

Comment: There are so many (more or less) different regular expression implementations out there. Please specify which language you are using.

Comment: Why don't you just iterate over all the matches of your regex?

Comment: @m0skit0 I was in a text editor and wanted to do a find&replace type thing

Answer (score 0):

Negating a regular expression is often pretty complicated.  Instead of deleting everything else with regular expressions, you are much better off finding all matches of your current regex and then joining the matches together to create a string of only the matches.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using grep and dumping the matches into a new file.